# Django Many to Many display values, not object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm working with Django 1.3, with the following 2 models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Trial(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True)
    strId = str(id)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.strId
```

I am trying to display all the entries of "name" to a view, but I am currently returning only <django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor object at 0x1019b45d0>

Which I can only see when I view the Page Source. Otherwise it just looks like a blank white screen.

The view is as follows:

```
def trial_entry(request, trial):
    currentTrial = Trial.objects.get(id = 1)
    personName = Trial.person
    return HttpResponse(personName)
```

I'm obviously returning the wrong thing here, but I've scoured for another way to do it and nothing I've found seems to work. This is about the only way I've found to return anything other than an error, so I figured that was the best thing to post.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here. First, `personName` is not accessing any actual instance of `Trial`, rather you are just getting information about the `person` attribute within the `Trial` class.

So the first thing you need to do is change how you fetch persons.

```
currentTrial = Trial.objects.get(pk=1)
personName = currentTrial.person
```

Do you see what's different? I access `currentTrial`, which is the instance of the `Trial` class you are dealing with, within this view. Makes sense so far?

Now, `currentTrial.person` is actually a ManyToMany manager, which can be iterated through, since we can have many persons on a Trial. So we should adjust the variable names to make a bit more sense.

```
persons = currentTrial.person.all()
```

You could go one step further and simply send `currentTrial` to the template context, and then access that trials persons within your template like so:

```
{% for person in currentTrial.person.all %}
      {{ person }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarity, I noticed you changed my `currentTrial = Trial.objects.get(id=1)` to `currentTrial = Trial.objects.get(pk=1)` . Is there a significance to using pk vs id in this case?

Comment: `pk` is an alias for the Primary Key that works whatever the primary key is called. By default the primary key is called `id` but this doesn't have to be the case. While it's fine to use `id` in your own projects (when you know the name will be `id`) it's good practice to use `pk` because it makes your code more portable.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Trial.person is a reference on the Trial model itself (the class), not an instance thereof. You should probably write it as `currentTrial.person` or `trial.person` depending on which trial you are interested in.

Secondly, you've used a many-to-many field for the person attirbute. This means that you can have multiple people associated with a trial - it would be more clearly named, 'people'.

If you really do mean people I'd suggest changing the name, but you actually get a queryset-like object back. You can do `person.all()` to get them all, or `person.filter(something=value)` to get a subset of the people associated with the trial.

If you really mean 'person' (a single preson associated with a trial) then you should use the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field. This will associate a single person with the trial that can be accessed with currentTrial.person.

Good luck!

Comment: Heh, near identical answers at the same time! +1 for you :-)